# Can't instantiate ArrayList of ArrayLists as a List of Lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a function that returns a list of lists of integers

`public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums)`

Obviously I can't directly instantiate a List so I chose to use an ArrayList and tried to instantiate my return value as such:

`List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

The above did not work but this did:

`List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

My understanding is that `List` is an interface that ArrayList inherits from. Why, then, can I instantiate an ArrayList of Lists and be ok but I can't instantiate an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

For readability the first few lines of my function look as such:

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if (nums.length < 3) return ans;
```

Comment: [A closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265) which has the distinct advantage of having been answered by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

This is because an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is NOT a `List<List<Integer>>`.

The reason is that a `List<List<Integer>>` is something that you should be able to add a `LinkedList<Integer>` to.  But you can't add a `LinkedList<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` because it's the wrong type.

Therefore, if you've got an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, you can never treat it as a `List<List<Integer>>`, or reference it with a variable of type `List<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 1):

This is Java Generics. `List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()` does not work because the outer list expects itself to keep `List<Integer>`, not `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Consider this:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This does not work either, because the list expects `Number`, not `Integer`.

Anyway when nesting lists, you need to instantiate inner lists as well. Lists of Lists do not work like multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't instantiate an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

because you specified type of `ans` as List of Lists not List of ArrayLists.

> `List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`
>
> The above did not work

I guess it will work if declaration will be:

`List<? extends List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Comment: True. Another way is to declare as List<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();. But the one mentioned in the above answer is the best as it is not coupled to any concrete implementaion of list